# Postgres cascades truncates to unrelated tables

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I've created a number of tables in my public schema.

Occasionally, I need to run a seeder to refresh the `users` table when I perform tests. To do this, I'm executing `TRUNCATE TABLE users RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE`.

However, I do not want any other tables but those related to the `users` table to be affected. The only foreign key referencing the `users` table is on the `teams` table which references `users` through `owner_id`. The `teams` table truncates as expected.

What isn't expected, is that the `attributes` table is also truncated by `TRUNCATE TABLE users RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE`.

The `attributes` table has one foreign key on the `accounts` table which references the `users` table. However, on the `attributes` table, ALL `account_id` values are `NULL` so there is no actual reference back on any of the records to a specific record in the `accounts` table. In fact, at the time of executing the truncate query, the entire `accounts` table is already empty.

How then is `TRUNCATE TABLE users RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE` causing my attributes table to be truncated based on `NULL` foreign keys?

Comment: I have a feeling that you got your foreign keys the other way around. I should think that with `CASCADE` all tables that _reference `users`_ should be truncated, not the other way around. So, from your description `teams` should _not_ be truncated.

Comment: If `attributes` is truncated by some trigger when you truncate `users`, then it should be a trigger on `users`, not on `attributes`.

Comment: @mustaccio you are correct. I wrote that out wrong by going off memory on the `teams` table. I've adjusted my post to make sense. I've also updated with additional information after looking closer at table structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `TRUNCATE ... CASCADE` [doesn't do any reference checking on foreign key values](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-truncate.html), that would defeat the purpose. The mere presense of referential integrity constraints connecting `attributes` to `users` via `accounts` causes all three (and possibly more) tables to be truncated (which you would have noticed if `accounts` weren't empty).